# BATCH call a label outside of batch script

Tags: label, call

I'm running a loop, whereby if a host (from a list) is online, a bunch of things happen to it. However, I want these things to happen independently to the main 'host checking' script, so that all hosts are processed almost concurrently.

Therefore, how can I achieve calling a label outside of the main batch script? I've tried variations of using the Start command to call :separatesub  with no luck yet. Thanks in advance!

@ ECHO Off

set a=19

if %a% == 1 (echo A is 1) else (start :separatesub)
pause

:separatesub
echo These actions will now be applied independently of the main batch script

:EOF

Answer (score 0):

You should use arguments

The main batch file:

```
@ ECHO Off
set a=19
if %a% == 1 (echo A is 1) else start MyLib.bat %a%
:EOF
```

The MyLib.bat file:

```
@ ECHO Off
if %1% == 19 goto Label19
:EOF
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
@ ECHO Off
set a=19
if %a% == 1 (echo A is 1) else (Call yourbatchfile.bat separatesub ) 
if %a% == 2 (echo A is 2) else (Call yourbatchfile.bat otherfunction param1 param2 ) 

pause
Goto:EOF
...
```

The magic happens with **Call:%*** in yourbatchfile.bat
It will work as a library of functions

**yourbatchfile.bat**

```
Call:%*
Goto:EOF

:separatesub
...
Goto:EOF

:otherfunction
...
Goto:EOF
```